# Excluding items from a list by object property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to build a list of items based on their presence in a list.

- `itemsAll` contains all products
- `itemsNew` contains only new products
- I'd like `itemsOld` to contain only old products (i.e. `itemsAll` -
  `itemsNew`)

This was my approach, which doesn't return the correct number of items.

```
var itemsAll = objProductStagingRepository.AllImports(fileId, cid).ToList();

var itemsNew = objProductStagingRepository.DetectNonPresentProductNames(fileId, cid).ToList();

var itemsOld = from t1 in itemsAll where !(from o in itemsNew select o.Id).Contains(t1.Id)
                                        select t1; // this does not work
```

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I shuold be approacing this?  I have tried `itemsAll.Except(itemsNew)` which also doesn't yield the correct results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably could use the Except method, but you would need to provide an equality comparer for the method to know when two items are equal.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx

In your question it looks like you're not using your own comparer, so it's comparing the items to see if they are the same object in memory (most likely), which is **not** what you're trying to do.

You want to compare the objects by database identity, which means you need to provide you're own comparer.

Example:

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

class ItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item x, Item y)
    {    
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item value)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(value, null)) return 0;

        int hash = value.Id.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
itemsOld.AddRange(itemsAll.Where(p => !itemsNew.Any(a => a.Id == p.Id)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the *fluent syntax* so:

```
var itemsOld = itemsAll.Where(x => !itemsNew.Any(y => y.Id == x.Id));
```

or

```
var itemsOld = itemsAll.Where(x => !itemsNew.Exists(y => y.Id == x.Id));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
var itemsOld = from a in itemsAll
               join n in itemsNew on a.Id equals n.Id into ng
               where !ng.Any()
               select a;
```